# Video.js: Make video maintain aspect ratio with max height

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am creating a website with a video page. I am using Video.js for the video player. Videos can be many different aspect ratios, anything from ultra widescreen to cellphone vertical video. I want the video player to maintain its aspect ratio. This can be accomplished by setting `fluid="true"` on the video element.

However, at certain aspect ratios this presents a problem. Vertical video for example, as it becomes the fluid width of its container will push the elements below it (like the video title) very far down the page and often offscreen. To prevent this from happening I wanted to set the max height of the video to something around `80vh`.

Consider the following snippets (when running the snippets do not expand them as that would increase the vertical space available, the goal here is to simulate a screen with very little vertical space):

Video.js video with `fluid="true"`. Since the aspect ratio of the video at the full width of the screen makes it taller than the screen the video title is pushed off the page:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    fluid="true"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <h1>Video Title</h1>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Video.js video with `fluid="true"` and `max-width: '150px'`. Since the width of the video is reduced the aspect ratio of the video does not push the video title off the page. However, this is not very useful to me since there is no easy way to set the max-width in a way that the video will never be taller than `80vh`:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>max-width = 150px</p>
  <div style="max-width: 150px">
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    fluid="true"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  </div>
  <h1>Video Title</h1>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Video.js video with `fluid="true"` and `max-height: '150px'`. Video.js ignores the max-height and pushes the video title off the page:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>max-height = 150px, but the video overflows the container</p>
  <div style="max-height: 150px">
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    fluid="true"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  </div>
  <h1>Video Title</h1>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

How can I make it so videos are cannot be taller than `80vh` while preserving aspect ratio in Video.js?

Comment: If the video has height less than 80vh do you want it to keep its original height rather than expand as far as it can? That's what I understood you to mean by max height but thought I'd better check.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to constrain the size of my video in the way YouTube does. The video height should be 80vh until there is not enough horizontal space left for the video to maintain its aspect ratio so the height shrinks.

Comment: While I think it may be possible to achieve this using video.js and a bit of post processing, it would be a hack and probably not easily maintainable. Is using video.js essential for your application or would a native JavaScript solution be acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth What do you mean by a native javascript solution, what would that entail? Video.js is necessary for the app because I am making use of many of its plugins. I find it hard to believe based on how often I encounter this situation for video elements and how widely used video.js is that there isn't a solution that is better than a hack?